# Safely kill foreground process when a background process ends

Tags: bash, kill, background-process

There are two scripts, the first in the background, the second in the foreground:

```
trap "ret=\$?; rm -f pipe1 pipe2; exit \$ret" EXIT INT TERM QUIT
my.bin > pipe1 < pipe2 &
my-term.sh pipe1 pipe2
```

`my-term.sh` interacts with the user via stdin/stdout (it's like a CLI terminal program):

```
while read -ep "prompt> " l; do echo $l; done
```

`my.bin` can be simulated with just `exit 0` script.

How to terminate `my-term.sh` if `my.bin` exits for any reason?

What works:

```
trap "ret=\$?; rm -f pipe1 pipe2; exit \$ret" EXIT INT TERM QUIT
(my.bin > pipe1 < pipe2; kill -9 $$) &
my-term.sh pipe1 pipe2
```

But it probably stops `my-term.sh` from cleanups. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try a list of signals, if one fails, wait three seconds, (sleep time may be tweaked based on whatever `my-term.sh` is supposed to be doing), then
try another:

```
(my.bin > pipe1 < pipe2; x=$$ ; \
 for sig in SIGTERM SIGINT SIGQUIT SIGABRT SIGKILL ; \
 do kill -${sig} $x && break ; sleep 3s ; done ; ) &
my-term.sh pipe1 pipe2
```

Comment: As, usual, I've posted an unreproducible example. Fixed now.